# Windows Asynchronous RPC C++ MIDL

Tags: c++, windows, hyperlink, rpc, midl

I have a MIDL generated C++ RPC interface from a client that defines two simple RPC functions.

I am trying to communicate with the server from a simple C++ application. I only have the header files - do I also need a client stub in order to successfully link my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make asynchronous RPC requests from the client you should definitely have a client stub file.

In case if you don't have a client stub, you have to compile the *.idl file with MIDL
When you do that you get the following output:

```
[filename].h   Header   
[filename]_c.c Client stub  
[filename]_s.c Server stub
```

If you don't have an access to the *.idl file, you may try to rewrite it from scratch using declarations taken from your *.h file.